# Reflection Method invoke cache

Tags: java, caching, reflection, invoke

I am attempting to use reflection Method.invoke() to execute a method based on  user inputted text that specifies the Class, Method and parameters to execute.  Something like this:

```
  public Object invokeInput(String className, String methodName, List<Object> list) {
        try {
            Class<?> cls = Class.forName(className);
            Method method = cls.getMethod(methodName, list.get(0).getClass());
            return method.invoke(null, list.get(0));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Everything works as intended for the first execution of the method, but then the results of the first invoke() seem to be saved/cached and returned for all subsequent calls to the same method when supplied method parameter Object (first Object in "list")  has the same reference, even though the internal fields of that parameter Object have changed and should result in a different method return.

Anyway to avoid this? or clear the cache somehow?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Reflection does not cache results. Either the method you're invoking is doing that, or you're observing the results of running some other code.

Comment: Can you also include your code where you are calling the `invokeInput` and also the list objects.

Comment: Thanks  rzwitserloot.  If the method being invoked is somehow caching the return, is there a way to get around it through the calling context?  (I don't have the ability to alter the method that is being called)

Comment: Deepak Patankar,
The invokeInput takes gets the list values and method/class names from a YAML input using SnakeYAML.  so the inputs are different at runtime.   Everything seems to be called the normal way though and works as intended during the first call but then just repeats the same return.  It might be the issue with the called method as rzwitserloot said